# Complex asof joins with option to select between duplicates + strictly less/greater than + use utf8

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way to perform something similar to an asof join, but with

1. The option to select which element to join with (e.g. first, last) if there are duplicates
2. The option to join with only strictly less/greater than
3. Ability to use utf-8

Here's a code example:

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'by_1': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'] * 8,
    'by_2': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'] * 8,
    'on_1': ['A'] * 16 + ['C'] * 16,
    'on_2': (['A'] * 8 + ['C'] * 8) * 2,
    '__index__': list(range(32))
})

df2 = pl.DataFrame([
    { 'by_1': 'Y', 'by_2': 'Y', 'on_1': 'B', 'on_2': 'A' },
    { 'by_1': 'Y', 'by_2': 'Y', 'on_1': 'C', 'on_2': 'A' },
    { 'by_1': 'Y', 'by_2': 'Z', 'on_1': 'A', 'on_2': 'A' },
])

df1:
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 ┆ by_2 ┆ on_1 ┆ on_2 ┆ __index__ │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 0         │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 1         │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 2         │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 3         │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 4         │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 5         │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 6         │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ 7         │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 8         │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 9         │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 10        │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 11        │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 12        │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 13        │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 14        │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ A    ┆ C    ┆ 15        │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 16        │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 17        │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 18        │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 19        │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 20        │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 21        │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 22        │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 23        │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 24        │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 25        │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 26        │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 27        │
│ X    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 28        │
│ X    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 29        │
│ Y    ┆ X    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 30        │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ C    ┆ 31        │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘

df2:
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ by_1 ┆ by_2 ┆ on_1 ┆ on_2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ B    ┆ A    │
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    │
│ Y    ┆ Z    ┆ A    ┆ A    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

```
# Case 1 - Less Than (lt)

df2.join_asof_lt(
    df1,
    by=['by_1', 'by_2'],
    on=['on_1', 'on_2'],
    lt_select_eq = 'first',
)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 ┆ by_2 ┆ on_1 ┆ on_2 ┆ __index__ │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ B    ┆ A    ┆ 11        │ # First strictly less than is ('Y', 'Y'), ('A', 'C'), which exists at index 11 and 15. Since lt_select_eq is 'first', choose 11
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 11        │ # First strictly less than is ('Y', 'Y'), ('A', 'C'), which exists at index 11 and 15. Since lt_select_eq is 'first', choose 11
│ Y    ┆ Z    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ null      │ # Group (Z, Y) does not exist, so return None
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘

df2.join_asof_lt(
    df1,
    by=['by_1', 'by_2'],
    on=['on_1', 'on_2'],
    lt_select_eq = 'last',
)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 ┆ by_2 ┆ on_1 ┆ on_2 ┆ __index__ │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ B    ┆ A    ┆ 15        │ # First strictly less than is ('Y', 'Y'), ('A', 'C'), which exists at index 11 and 15. Since lt_select_eq is 'last', choose 15
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 15        │ # First strictly less than is ('Y', 'Y'), ('A', 'C'), which exists at index 11 and 15. Since lt_select_eq is 'last', choose 15
│ Y    ┆ Z    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ null      │ # Group (Z, Y) does not exist, so return None
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘


# Case 2 - Less Than or Equal To (leq)

df2.join_asof_leq(
    df1,
    by=['by_1', 'by_2'],
    on=['on_1', 'on_2'],
    lt_select_eq = 'first',
    eq_select_eq = 'last',
)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 ┆ by_2 ┆ on_1 ┆ on_2 ┆ __index__ │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ B    ┆ A    ┆ 11        │ # First less than or equal to is ('Y', 'Y'), ('A', 'C'), which exists at index 11 and 15. Since lt_select_eq is 'first', choose 11
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 23        │ # First less than or equal to is ('Y', 'Y'), ('C', 'A'), which exists at index 19 and 23. Since eq_select_eq is 'last', choose 23
│ Y    ┆ Z    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ null      │ # Group (Z, Y) does not exist, so return None
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘

df2.join_asof_leq(
    df1,
    by=['by_1', 'by_2'],
    on=['on_1', 'on_2'],
    lt_select_eq = 'last',
    eq_select_eq = 'first',
)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 ┆ by_2 ┆ on_1 ┆ on_2 ┆ __index__ │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ B    ┆ A    ┆ 15        │ # First less than or equal to is ('Y', 'Y'), ('A', 'C'), which exists at index 11 and 15. Since lt_select_eq is 'last', choose 15
│ Y    ┆ Y    ┆ C    ┆ A    ┆ 19        │ # First less than or equal to is ('Y', 'Y'), ('C', 'A'), which exists at index 19 and 23. Since eq_select_eq is 'first', choose 19
│ Y    ┆ Z    ┆ A    ┆ A    ┆ null      │ # Group (Z, Y) does not exist, so return None
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

These examples are for lt / leq, but it could also be gt / geq. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but - I'm guessing there is a reason a regular join/filter cannot work for you? `df2.join(df1, on=["by_1", "by_2"], how="left").filter(...)`

Comment: @jqurious Left joins only match for exact results, whereas asof joins match the nearest results

Comment: Yes, but I mean joining just on the `by` columns which are exact - then filtering out near results from the result of the join. I'm guessing you have large amounts of data and that is too slow, and you want to reduce the search space for potential matches? Thanks.

Comment: @jqurious Sorry I don't quite understand - would you be able to provide an example for how you would use a left join, say for one of the simple cases in the question? Thanks

Comment: I've added it as an "answer" to make it easier to read. Perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow why `3` and `7` are not to be classed as less than but for example:

```
df3 = df2.join(df1, on=["by_1", "by_2"], how="left")
df3.filter(
   pl.col("__index__").is_null() |
   (pl.col("on_1_right") < pl.col("on_1"))
)
```

```
shape: (9, 7)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 | by_2 | on_1 | on_2 | on_1_right | on_2_right | __index__ │
│ ---  | ---  | ---  | ---  | ---        | ---        | ---       │
│ str  | str  | str  | str  | str        | str        | i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | A          | A          | 3         │
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | A          | A          | 7         │
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | A          | C          | 11        │
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | A          | C          | 15        │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | A          | A          | 3         │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | A          | A          | 7         │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | A          | C          | 11        │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | A          | C          | 15        │
│ Y    | Z    | A    | A    | null       | null       | null      │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

Get "closest" match per group:

```
group_keys = ["by_1", "by_2", "on_1", "on_2"]

df3 = df2.join(df1, on=["by_1", "by_2"], how="left")
(
   df3
   .filter(
      pl.col("__index__").is_null() |
      (pl.col("on_1") > pl.col("on_1_right")))
   .filter(
      pl.col([
         "on_1_right", 
         "on_2_right"
      ]) == pl.col(["on_1_right", "on_2_right"])
            .last()
            .over(group_keys))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 7)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 | by_2 | on_1 | on_2 | on_1_right | on_2_right | __index__ │
│ ---  | ---  | ---  | ---  | ---        | ---        | ---       │
│ str  | str  | str  | str  | str        | str        | i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | A          | C          | 11        │
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | A          | C          | 15        │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | A          | C          | 11        │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | A          | C          | 15        │
│ Y    | Z    | A    | A    | null       | null       | null      │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

If you `.groupby(group_keys)` that result you can use `.first()` / `.last()`

```
>>> groups.agg(pl.col("__index__").first())
shape: (3, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 | by_2 | on_1 | on_2 | __index__ │
│ ---  | ---  | ---  | ---  | ---       │
│ str  | str  | str  | str  | i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | 11        │
│ Y    | Z    | A    | A    | null      │
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | 11        │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

```
>>> groups.agg(pl.col("__index__").last())
shape: (3, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ by_1 | by_2 | on_1 | on_2 | __index__ │
│ ---  | ---  | ---  | ---  | ---       │
│ str  | str  | str  | str  | i64       │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Y    | Y    | B    | A    | 15        │
│ Y    | Z    | A    | A    | null      │
│ Y    | Y    | C    | A    | 15        │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot, but now I see the misundertanding. index `3` and `7` are indeed less. However, when I specify "first", I want the **closest** element less than ('B', 'A'), which is ('A', 'C') which exists at index 11 and 15, and if there are duplicates I want to take the first one, hence 11. The case for "last" is the default for the current join_asof, so this is really more for the case of "first"

Comment: If the rows are sorted that would mean the last `on_*_right` values for each group are the closest - right? So you could filter those out. I've added an example.